# Read lines from a .txt to a table of objects

Tags: java, object, methods, text-files

I need help; what I'm trying to do is to put each line of a text file into an table of object.
Let's get into example :

I have that text file:

```
ATI
8
10
AMX
12
15
```

As we can see, this text file contain different types of mother boards.

So I have this constructor (which is on another class) of mother boards objects:

```
motherBoard(String type, int size, int max_size){
this.type = type;
this.size = size;
this.max_size = max_size;
}
```

So what I'm trying to do is to make a table of object where (in this example) the first object of the table would contain the 3 first lines of the text file. Then, the 2nd object of the table would contain the next 3 lines so on...

All the operations I want to do are in a method...
Here is my code so far :

```
public static CarteMere[] chargerEnMemoire(String nomFichier) throws IOException{
    CarteMere[] newCarteMere = new CarteMere[0];
    try {
        FileReader reader = new FileReader( "liste.txt" );
        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader( reader );
        int nmLines = 0;
        while ( buffer.ready() ) {
            nmLines++; // To evaluate the size of the table
        }
        buffer.close();
        newCarteMere = new CarteMere[nmLines/3];
        for(int i=0; i<(nmLines/3);i++){

        }
    } catch ( FileNotFoundException e ) {
        System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
    } catch ( IOException e ) {
        System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
    }

    return newCarteMere;
}
```

That's where I need a push...

Comment: so where is the problem exactly? Where do u get error? what type of error? Or you need help in coding logic for the above

Comment: Are you sure there always be 3 lines in a group ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found a way... I think i found a solution...

Here is my new code :

```
public static CarteMere[] chargerEnMemoire(String nomFichier) throws IOException{
    CarteMere[] newCarteMere = new CarteMere[0];
    try {
        FileReader reader = new FileReader( nomFichier );
        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader( reader );
        int nmLines = 0;
        while ( buffer.readLine() != null) {
            nmLines++; // To evaluate the size of the table
                        }
        buffer.close();
        reader.close();
        //RESET THE BUFFER AND READER TO GET ON TOP OF THE FILE
        FileReader reader2 = new FileReader( nomFichier );
        BufferedReader buffer2 = new BufferedReader( reader2 );
        newCarteMere = new CarteMere[nmLines/3];
        for(int i=0; i<(nmLines/3);i++){
            int forme = CarteMere.chaineFormeVersCode(buffer2.readLine());
            int mem_inst = Integer.parseInt(buffer2.readLine());
            int mem_max = Integer.parseInt(buffer2.readLine());
            newCarteMere[i] = new CarteMere(forme, mem_inst, mem_max);
        }
        buffer2.close();
        reader2.close();
    } catch ( FileNotFoundException e ) {
        System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
    } catch ( IOException e ) {
        System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
    }

    return newCarteMere;
}
```

But the idea of reseting the buffer and redear like that seems ugly to me... Do you guys have an idea to do the same sime but more correctly ?

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

Start with what you know, you have a file, it contains data in groups of three lines, one's a `String`, the other two are numbers.

You have a class which represents that data, always easier to store data in an object where possible, so you could do something like...

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("liste.txt"))) {
    String name = br.readLine();
    int size = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    int max = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

    Motherboard mb = new MotherBoard(name, size, max);
    // Add it to a List or what ever else you want to do it...
} catch (IOException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you have getter and setter for all 3 variables in your pojo class and you have overloaded toString() method in motherBoard class,

```
Integer noOfLines=0, i=0, j=0;
String [] data=null;
String sCurrentLine=null;
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("liste.txt"));
while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) 
{
    noOfLines++;
    data[i]=sCurrentLine;
} 
i=-1;
j=noOfLines/3;
motherBoard mb=null;
for(int x=0;x<=j;x++)
{
    mb=new motherBoard(data[++i], Integer.parseInt(data[++i]), Integer.parseInt(data[++i]))
    System.out.println(mb);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding just reading the data from a file and loading it into classes, hopefully this example will help you:

**MotherBoard.java**

```
public class MotherBoard {
    String type;
    int size;
    int max_size;

    public MotherBoard (String type, int size, int max_size) {
        this.type = type;
        this.size = size;
        this.max_size = max_size;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Motherboard data : type=" + type + " size=" + size + ", max_size=" + max_size;
    }
}
```

**Solution.java:**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            FileReader reader = new FileReader( "liste.txt" );
            BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader( reader );
            int nmLines = 0;
            int numMBs = 0;
            while (buffer.ready()) {
                numMBs++;
                /* Not a good approach if your data isn't perfect - just an example for StackOverflow */
                MotherBoard mb = new MotherBoard (buffer.readLine(),
                        Integer.parseInt(buffer.readLine()),
                        Integer.parseInt(buffer.readLine()));
                System.out.println("Motherboard " + numMBs + ":");
                System.out.println(mb.toString());
            }
            /* Probably want to do this in a finally block too */
            buffer.close();
            reader.close();
        } catch ( FileNotFoundException e ) {
            System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
        } catch ( IOException e ) {
            System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
        }
    }
}
```

To compile and run:

```
javac -cp . MotherBoard.java Solution.java 
java Solution
```

Output:

```
Motherboard 1:
Motherboard data : type=ATI size=8, max_size=10
Motherboard 2:
Motherboard data : type=AMX size=12, max_size=15
```